# Convert tab to spaces

Tags: coding-style

Usually we replace tabs to spaces in editors while coding.
What is the exact need for that?

Is it for because the OS handles \t in the files?
I am really not very sure of this. Kindly clarify

Answer (score 0):

**Tabs don't have fixed width**, its width **depends on IDE (editor) settings**. It is usually set to have width 4 spaces, but it doesn't have to be. There probably wouldn' be any problem if you use only tabs and don't use spaces, but this will never happen. You can bet, you will always want to move some text by only one extra space to the right. Then you will be **mixing spaces and tabs** together and that's what **brings trouble**. It might look correct in your IDE, but then you will want to do some change in vim editor for example, where there will be different tab size set. Indentation of the code won't be what would you expect. Also when you send some code to your co-worker, he might use different IDE with different settings and he will again see wrongly aligned code. On the other hand **with spaces** only **you see what see the others**.